# A question concerning Cesaro-Stolz theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Someone has posted a question about evaluating
$$
A \colon =\lim_{\mathbb N^* \ni n \to \infty }\frac {1^n + 2^n + \cdots + n^n} {n^n},
$$
and I thought I could apply Cesaro-Stolz theorem, because the denominator $n^n \nearrow +\infty$. But if I apply it, then I get
$$
A = \lim_n \frac {(n+1)^{n+1}} {(n+1)^{n+1} - n^n} = \lim_n \frac {\left( 1 + \dfrac 1n\right)^{n+1}} {\left( 1 + \dfrac 1n\right)^{n+1} - \dfrac 1n} = \frac {\mathrm e}{\mathrm e - 0} = 1,
$$
instead of $\mathrm e / (\mathrm e - 1)$. What happened here?

Possible duplicate from following post:  [Understanding $(\frac{1}{n})^n+(\frac{2}{n})^n+...+(\frac{n}{n})^n$ sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2875422/514490)

Older post: [How to evaluate $ \lim \limits_{n\to \infty} \sum \limits_ {k=1}^n \frac{k^n}{n^n}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/164074/514490)

Comment: the numerator is not $(n+1)^{n+1}$.

Comment: @user108128 Thanks, I notice it now.

Comment: But why is the denominator not $(n+1)^{n+1}$?

Comment: @Szeto It should be $$ \sum_1^{n+1} j^{n+1} - \sum_1^n j^n$$, which clearly does not equal $(n+1)^{n+1}$

Comment: @xbh Ah! I even typed ‘denominator’ in my comment! I better get some rest.

Comment: @Szeto Maybe ;) Take care

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @user108128. This is purely my mistake. Maybe this is a lesson for someone read the post could learn [or not, cause this mistake is the “inferior” type].

Comment: Please elaborate what @user108128 stated as soln., as his response is not any more visible.

Comment: Basically the same as Nosrati stated. The explanations were also given in the following comment.